# Cannot find (visible) type for alias o within [aoe:AbstractOrderEntry, oe:OrderEntryItem]

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I am trying to join 2 tables in flexible search query (OrderEntryItem and AbstractOrderEntry) filtering by BaseStoreModel

```
select {oe.pk} from {OrderEntryItem as oe join AbstractOrderEntry as aoe on {oe.abstractOrderEntry} = {aoe.pk}} where {aoe.order} in (select {o.pk} from {AbstractOrder as o where {o.store} = ?store)
```

But i have the following error:
cannot find (visible) type for alias o within [aoe:AbstractOrderEntry, oe:OrderEntryItem]

Comment: The OOTB hybris hasn't got OrderEntryItem type. Maybe it is your own type. OrderEntryItem, AbstractOrderEntry looks same type. What are you trying to achive? Are trying to get all order items? Then try to join Order and OrderEntry with OrderEntry.order property.
select {oe.pk} from {OrderEntry as oe join Order as o on {oe.order} = {o.pk}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS instead of IN keyword in flexi query.
You can get support from this . [link](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12756159/problem-with-flexible-search-query-with-exists-cla.html)

If you want use "IN" keyword, you have a syntax problem.
you need to use two curly braces.

**For example;**

```
SELECT {PK} FROM {Product} WHERE {code} IN ( {{ SELECT {code} FROM {Product} WHERE {unit}=unit1 }})
```